# Maven/ Nexus - Automatic Dependency Update

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus

I'm having a bit of an issue and was wondering if there is any way to do this.

Essentially, my team maintains a "core" that contains common code that is used across all of our projects. Naturally, we used Maven to manage it across our projects, but an issue has come up. Essentially, after updating the "core", we have Jenkins set up to build it and deploy it to a private Nexus repository. This all works fine.

The issue I am having is that these changes we apply are usually to add something we happened to miss or move something that we find to be rewriting often to the "core". However, Maven takes time to update the dependencies (unless we completely flush the local Maven cache, which is less than ideal). So the question I have is how can I get around this to where Maven will "automatically" (it could be at the click of a button or the use of a command [currently trying to update it through normal methods don't update it]) update the local repository. We are currently using the "Releases" repository rather than the "Snapshots", but of course we can change if needed.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you deploying the changed `core` with a new version number? Are you depending just on `core`, or on some specific version in your projects? Have you tried `mvn -U ...`?

Comment: I'd prefer to use the same version number so I don't have to update it each time there is a commit. And ```mvn clean install -U``` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same version for updated artifact goes against Maven's expectations - the release (non-snapshot) version is assumed to be final and unchanging, it should uniquely identify the assembled artifact. Changing the release version code without updating version can produce irrepeatable builds!

You could use snapshot versions instead, or build the core as new version every time and either update the dependencies where needed or use [version range](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#ex-dep-range) - like `[1.5,)`.

---

Personally, I would use SNAPSHOT versions if the core changes often and project releases are relatively rare (keep in mind you should then build a release version of the core whenever you release any of the depending projects!), and would use new core release with new version every time if the core is relatively stable compared to how often the depending projects are released.

If you use version range to define the core dependency, you should update the range in the depending projects whenever you make an API-breaking change in core (when you do this, the projects that depend on old API must now reference version range that stops short of this new version (or namely the previous version instead of range), and projects dependent on the new API must use version range starting with the current version).

Comment: Thank you! I feel like this is a better plan than the one I am currently using.

Answer (score 1):

As already others say using the samve version for a changed artifacts does not make sense not only in Maven also in general. 
If you do some development on your core component which is used by a larger number of other projects than your component should have a usual releases which means you start with `1.0.0`..doing some bug fixes you might get `1.0.1` or some other enhancement you could use `1.1.0` etc. So now to the consuming projects. There you can use versions-maven-plugin to update the dependencies. Apart from that if you have done it the right way in Mave you have defined the dependencies to the core in a central location via dependencyManagement which the version should be only a single location which means updating is simply updating a single line in a pom so i don't see a real issue here and this can be done via `versions-maven-plugin` as well and an further step is to do this via a jenkins job...And of course the way during heavy development in core you could use a `-SNAPSHOT` reference...

One of the foundations in Maven and also other tools like that is that a release version is immutable.